# How does WP Greet Box work?

Tags: php, blogs, wordpress, referrer

I have noticed some blogs using what looks like a wordpress plugin to detect if the website visitor came from google search. how is this done?

http://omninoggin.com/projects/wordpress-plugins/wp-greet-box-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin checks the [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) value (since it is written in PHP) which holds the [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) of the loaded page, then parses it to check what site the user came from to welcome them accordingly.